# Polymorphism and pre validating class attributes

Tags: java

Basically I have been tasked with tackling the following scenario:

When you are designing your class/es, you have to decide what attributes and methods you will include in. For example, if you decide to work in millimeters, your `size` variable (length) could be of type integer (but later, when calculating the cost, you will have to convert the volume into square inches, because the cost is given per cubic inch of plastic (Table 2 and Table 3 of the coursework)). The volume of plastic material used will be the difference between the outer and inner volume of a pipe. If you decided to prompt the length in meters, then the type should be double, or float, etc.
Once you have validated the user order, your program should determine, based on Table 1, what is the type of the ordered pipe.
Table 1.  Types of plastic pipes available.

```
Type Plastic’s grade    Colour print    Inner insulation    Outer reinforcement Chemical resistance
        0     1 2           
I   1 – 3   YES NO  NO  NO  NO  YES/NO
II  2 – 4   NO  YES NO  NO  NO  YES/NO
III 2 – 5   NO  NO  YES NO  NO  YES/NO
IV  2 – 5   NO  NO  YES YES NO  YES/NO
V   3 – 5   NO  NO  YES YES YES YES/NO
```

That's all fine but the part that is getting me is this bit here:

Say in your main class you have determined that client’s order is a pipe of type I, then you can create an object of `TypeI`  and for this object you can call the cost() method to calculate the cost and to show it to the user.

It is basically asking to not instantiate any objects before figuring out which one you need to instantiate, which is hard when it classes a big if statement in the verification as a 'Brute force method'.

Here is what I have so far.

Main

```
public class Cw1 {
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Pipe> pipeList = new ArrayList<Pipe>();
    // TODO code application logic here
    Grade g1 = new Grade(1,3,true,false,false,false,false);
    Grade g2 = new Grade(2,4,false,true,false,false,false);
    Grade g3 = new Grade(2,5,false,false,true,false,false);
    Grade g4 = new Grade(2,5,false,false,true,true,false);
    Grade g5 = new Grade(3,5,false,false,true,true,true);
    pipeList.add(g1);
    pipeList.add(g2);
    pipeList.add(g3);
    pipeList.add(g4);
    pipeList.add(g5);

    for (Pipe p: pipeList)
    {
        p.setGrade(1);
        p.setColour0(false);
        p.setColour1(false);
        p.setColour2(true);
        p.setIns(true);
        p.setReinf(true);
        p.validate();
    }
}
}
```

Grade (It must have abstracting in the solution)

```
public class Grade extends Pipe {

public Grade(int minGrade, int maxGrade, boolean hasColour0, boolean hasColour1, boolean hasColour2, boolean hasIns, boolean hasReinf) {
    super(minGrade, maxGrade, hasColour0, hasColour1, hasColour2, hasIns, hasReinf);
}    


}
```

And pipe

```
public abstract class Pipe {

public boolean isChemRes() {
    return chemRes;
}

public void setChemRes(boolean chemRes) {
    this.chemRes = chemRes;
}

public boolean isColour0() {
    return colour0;
}

public void setColour0(boolean colour0) {
    this.colour0 = colour0;
}

public boolean isColour1() {
    return colour1;
}

public void setColour1(boolean colour1) {
    this.colour1 = colour1;
}

public boolean isColour2() {
    return colour2;
}

public void setColour2(boolean colour2) {
    this.colour2 = colour2;
}

public double getDiameter() {
    return diameter;
}

public void setDiameter(double diameter) {
    this.diameter = diameter;
}

public boolean isIns() {
    return ins;
}

public void setIns(boolean ins) {
    this.ins = ins;
}

public double getLength() {
    return length;
}

public void setLength(double length) {
    this.length = length;
}

public boolean isReinf() {
    return reinf;
}

public void setReinf(boolean reinf) {
    this.reinf = reinf;
}

public Pipe(int minGrade, int maxGrade, boolean hasColour0, boolean hasColour1, boolean hasColour2, boolean hasIns, boolean hasReinf) {
    this.minGrade = minGrade;
    this.maxGrade = maxGrade;
    this.hasColour0 = hasColour0;
    this.hasColour1 = hasColour1;
    this.hasColour2 = hasColour2;
    this.hasIns = hasIns;
    this.hasReinf = hasReinf;
}



public Pipe() {
}
//<editor-fold desc="Class variables">
private int grade;
private double length, diameter;
private boolean colour0, colour1, colour2, ins, reinf, chemRes;
private int minGrade, maxGrade;
private boolean hasColour0, hasColour1, hasColour2, hasIns, hasReinf; 
// </editor-fold>
public int getGrade() {
    return grade;
}

public void setGrade(int grade) {
    this.grade = grade;
}    
//<editor-fold desc="Public Methods">

public double calcVol()
{
    return 0;
}

public double calcCost()
{
    return 0;
}
public void validate()
{
    if ((grade >= minGrade && grade <= maxGrade) & (colour0 == true && hasColour0 || colour1 == true && hasColour1 || colour2 == true && hasColour2) && (ins == hasIns) && (reinf == hasReinf))
    {
        System.out.print("True");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.print("False");
    }
}
// </editor-fold>

}
```

So basically, I don't understand how I could achieve the same result without instantiating the objects before hand and validating them?

The class isn't high level, we have only just learned polymorphism.

Comment: What a terrible title - please edit it to something _descriptive_ of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, the data which tells you which objects to create comes from an external source: a file, a socket, another object etc. In your case, you could use a text file. Create the `Grade` instances passing the values you read to the constructor and then call `validate` and `cost` on each.

```
public class PipeFactory(){
    public Pipe CreatePipe( int minGrade, int maxGrade, boolean hasColour0, boolean hasColour1, boolean hasColour2, boolean hasIns, boolean hasReinf ){
       if( (minGrade == 1 || maxGrade == 3) /* ... Complete this condition yourself */ )
           return new TypeIPipe();
       if( (minGrade == 2 || maxGrade == 4 /* ... Complete this condition yourself */ )
           return new TypeIIPipe();
       //If for other types...
       //If no pipe was created, parameters are invalid, so we throw an exception
       throw new InvalidArgumentException( "Can't create a pipe with these parameters" );
    } 
}
```

Comment: Well the data will be coming from the UI, the problem is as I mentioned in the original post that they seem to have a problem with a big if statement that figures out which type of pipe it is as soon as the user clicks a button, it needs to take a more object orientated approach.

Comment: In that case, create a `PipeFactory` class, with a `CreatePipe` method, and write your big `if` there. That's perfectly acceptable OOP: the `PipeFactory` class's responsibility would be creating the right concrete `Pipe` given certain parameters. If not, it's a chicken and egg problem; your only other alternative would be Reflection

Comment: By the way, since we're talking about OOP: You're not really using polymorphism here; you only have one subclass, so all calls to `cost` and `validate` will always have the same behavior (they will be "monomorphic" calls, if you will). On the other hand, if you had more than one subclass of `Pipe`, each with its own overriden version of `cost` and `validate`, and you called them via a `Pipe` reference, without caring about the concrete class behind, now that would be polymorphism

Comment: Thanks, this is first year Java though, the second suggestion sounds like a more feasible option although even having a different subclass for each type of pipe would mean I would still need to instantiate each class before I know which one is the right one though right?

Comment: No. You need to know, after reading the parameters, if you need to create an instance of `TypeI`, `TypeII`, etc. I'll update my answer with some code.

Comment: There. If you see that conditions grow too long, consider turning them into private boolean methods of the `PipeFactory` class

Comment: Thanks for providing the code, in this case it will only have a single class instantiated as a type of controller which then creates grades types of pipe to calculate cost / other things if I am right and that PipeFactory could be seen as the UI class?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5444/discussion-between-dario-ramos-and-jamieb)